Calculate a mean value for column C for all dates less than the date in row R with Pandas
I have a pandas dataframe with >101K rows from which I am trying to calculate a mean value for the won column based upon date. The logic is that for each row, find the mean value of won for all rows where row['created_on'] < current row['created_on']. Please note that I am not trying to achieve a cumulative mean value for the won column as this question was identified as a duplicate. The suggested duplicate provides a means of calculating a cumulative value by row but I'm looking to try and calculate a cumulative value by date, i.e., all values for rolling_won_prop should be the same for a given date but should not be cumulative by row.
I can calculate a simple value with
def get_win_prop(df, d) -> float:
    mask = (df['created_on'] < d)
    prop = df[mask].won.mean()
    return(prop)

get_win_prop(d, '2022-10-25')

I get no errors when I try to use this function with pd.assign() but all values end up being NaN:
d.assign(rolling_won_prop = lambda x: get_win_prop(x, x.created_on))


What am I missing? I would have assumed the get_win_prop() fx to be what I needed. Is there a more efficient way to do this in pandas? Note that I have supplied a sample of data below but that I will need to group by a customer ID column before calculating the get_win_prop() value.
UPDATE 1
I have come up with a sample solution that work for this toy dataset below but may not scale well:
result = []
for i in d.created_on.unique():
    prev_vals = d[d['created_on'] < i]
    result.append(prev_vals.won.mean())


d.merge(pd.DataFrame({'created_on': d.created_on.unique(), 
                      'rolling_won_prop ': result}), how = 'left')


Update 2
I hacked together an inelegant solution with a for loop that produces appropriate results:
results = []

for i in d.created_on.unique():
    prev_vals = d[d['created_on'] < i]
    results.append(prev_vals.won.mean())


d.merge(pd.DataFrame({'created_on': d.created_on.unique(), 
                       'rolling_won_prop ': results}), how = 'left')


Given I have an additional column for customer ID (not present in the MWE presented here), I can adapt the above solution to group by the customer ID, but this is still not idea. I'd much rather have this solution in a pandas framework, if possible.
Sample data
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

d = pd.DataFrame({'created_on': [Timestamp('2022-09-22 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-10-14 00:00:00'),Timestamp('2022-10-19 00:00:00'),Timestamp('2022-10-25 00:00:00'),Timestamp('2022-11-02 00:00:00'),
                Timestamp('2022-11-04 00:00:00'),Timestamp('2022-11-16 00:00:00'),Timestamp('2022-11-28 00:00:00'),Timestamp('2022-11-28 00:00:00'),Timestamp('2022-12-07 00:00:00'),
                Timestamp('2022-12-21 00:00:00'),Timestamp('2022-12-21 00:00:00'),Timestamp('2022-12-21 00:00:00'),Timestamp('2022-12-21 00:00:00')],
  'n_lines': [7, 3, 7, 6, 6, 4, 5, 3, 10, 3, 6, 6, 9, 6],
  'n_pieces': [606, 202, 706, 765, 255, 803, 1004, 2702, 1909, 546, 555, 555, 558,555],
  'quote_total': [1780.4299999999998, 3575.4600000000005, 11762.079999999994, 6725.160000000002, 995.9300000000001, 1644.2100000000003, 2620.2299999999996,
                   8082.090000000001, 5302.320000000001, 1959.7599999999998, 8734.67, 9792.3, 0.0, 9720.71],
  'won': [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]})


@ouroboros1 I appreciate the question you suggested as a duplicate but the answer there does not provide what I'm looking for. It gives a cumulative mean by row rather than finding the mean('won'') for all rows less than row['created_on']. For example, the final four lines in the example data I provided should all have the same rolling_won_prop value rather than a decreasing value. I'll edit the question to reflect why the suggested duplicate isn't really.

Apologies, I missed that you have duplicate dates in column 'created_on'. Can one at least assume that your dates are sorted per id?

@ouroboros1 Yes, that's a fair assumption.

I added an inelegant solution in UPDATE 2 that works, but would prefer a Pandas solution, if possible.

Assuming that dates are sorted per 'id', you can still benefit from the linked post. You can overwrite the values of the new column with the first value for the duplicate combinations of['id', 'group'] afterwards. Meaning:
Minimal reproducible example with 'id' groups
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'id': np.repeat(['A', 'B'], [6,6]),
        'created_on': np.tile(np.repeat(pd.date_range('2024-01-01', periods=4), 
                                        [1,2,1,2]), 2),
        'won': np.tile([1, 0], 6)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df

   id created_on  won
0   A 2024-01-01    1
1   A 2024-01-02    0
2   A 2024-01-02    1
3   A 2024-01-03    0
4   A 2024-01-04    1
5   A 2024-01-04    0
6   B 2024-01-01    1
7   B 2024-01-02    0
8   B 2024-01-02    1
9   B 2024-01-03    0
10  B 2024-01-04    1
11  B 2024-01-04    0

Code
gp = df.groupby('id')['won']
df['rolling_won_prop'] = (gp.cumsum() - df['won'])/gp.cumcount()
df['rolling_won_prop'] = (df.groupby(['id', 'created_on'])
                          ['rolling_won_prop'].transform('first')
                          )

Output:
   id created_on  won  rolling_won_prop
0   A 2024-01-01    1               NaN
1   A 2024-01-02    0          1.000000
2   A 2024-01-02    1          1.000000 
3   A 2024-01-03    0          0.666667 # e.g. (1 + 0 + 1) / 3
4   A 2024-01-04    1          0.500000 # e.g. (1 + 0 + 1 + 0) / 4
5   A 2024-01-04    0          0.500000 # filled from prev row
6   B 2024-01-01    1               NaN
7   B 2024-01-02    0          1.000000
8   B 2024-01-02    1          1.000000
9   B 2024-01-03    0          0.666667
10  B 2024-01-04    1          0.500000
11  B 2024-01-04    0          0.500000

Or using expanding similar to the other answer from the linked post, but with transform:
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

df2['rolling_won_prop'] = (df2.groupby('id')
                           ['won'].transform(lambda x: 
                                             x.expanding().mean().shift(1)
                                             )
                               )
df2['rolling_won_prop'] = (df2.groupby(['id', 'created_on'])
                          ['rolling_won_prop'].transform('first')
                          )

df.equals(df2)
# True

